# Grails compilation errors with xml-apis - SAXParserException

Tags: grails, compilation

My lib directory only has 1 jar. xml-apis 2.8.1. When I remove it, everything compiles. This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Class org/xml/sax/SAXParseException violates loader constraints
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The `xml-apis` classes are included in the JRE. This issue is also known as being part of the ["jar hell"](http://tech-read.com/2009/01/13/what-is-jar-hell/) problem, and - in the JVM space - typically occurs with XML libraries being included multiple times in the classpath, i.e. from the JRE `rt.jar`, by the application server or as a dependency of third-party libraries. This leads to `LinkageError` exceptions as the one provided above.

This is one example that describes how [to solve this issue in Grails 1.3.7](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/08/27/grails-1-3-7-and-the-dreaded-saxparseexception.html).